# Should I delete my question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I had asked a question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119166/), then users answered it in comments section. after I read the comments, I feel the question is not valid.

Should I delete it?

Comment: It's entirely up to you if you want to delete it. I wouldn't though, because what if someone feels like explaining why exactly ''thing'' would not work without an article there.